# Connecting HTML to CSS not working

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7hoU.png)
The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<title>Slideshow</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery Cycle Slideshow/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery Cycle Slideshow/js/cycle2.js"></script>
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="cssforsliding.css">
</head>

<body>
```

The stylesheet:

```
 * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 704px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: black;
    ...
```

I am using notepad++ and I have saved my CSS file in the notepad++ documents file as cssforsliding.css and I believe I have linked my HTML and CSS correctly but it doesn't seem to be working!

Help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Sorry I should have been clearer: the CSS part in my question is the CSS for an EXTERNAL CSS file. So I actually want to link my HTML to an EXTERNAL CSS file.

EDIT2: I have moved my css file inside another folder within the folder where my HTML (and CSS) is located and specify that folder in my HTML and now it works strangely! Thanks everyone :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soLH0.png)

Comment: Is your CSS file a sibling to your HTML file or is it in a folder? We can't help you without information on your folder structure

Comment: Check your path for your linked CSS file, this assumes it's in the same folder as your HTML file.

Comment: @NicholasMa what is the folder structure of your website

Comment: Hey Lee, yeah they are on the same file already.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the code you supplied. Check the Developer Tools in your browser. Look at the Network tab. See if everything is loading correctly. Add HTML that the CSS will effect to make sure you are right about it failing to link correctly.

Comment: Paste the screenshot of your folder structure.

Comment: @AndyHolmes both my CSS file (CSS document), called cssforsliding.css and my HTML file (Chrome HTML document), called 2ndTest are in the same file. :)

Comment: @NicholasMa — I think you mean "directory"

Comment: @Quentin Yup yup :)

Comment: I have already added an image, hope it helps!

Comment: That should work fine! Press CTRL + u and right on cssforsliding.css and say open link in new tab (Not for IE).

Comment: It is still not working! @HiteshMisro I have attached another image at the top to show that. :(

Comment: I moved my css file to another folder inside the folder where my HTML is contained and linked my HTML to that CSS file by specifying that folder and now it works somehow! O.O

Answer (score -1):

I can't try this solution at the machine I'm on (at work), but it might work if you just close the tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="cssforsliding.css" />
```

If not, it looks tidier and follows HTML5 in any case.

Comment: No. The `/` is an XHTML thing. It only makes a difference if the OP was using XHTML. If this was the solution to their problem, then their problem would be that the browser was showing the yellow screen of death and not that the stylesheet wasn't applying. (in HTML 5 the `/` is allowed, but only to make people and syntax highlighters that are addicted to XHTML feel better, it makes no practical difference (the extra byte is bloat, but not much bloat)).

Answer (score -2):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssforsliding.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 704px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: black;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when we use link tag => we put our style in external sheet

Comment: when we use style we add our style in same html file 

we can add both

Comment: That's not explaining what's different. I mean, explain the use of the `<style>` element

Comment: "when we use style we add our style in same html file" — The OP said they didn't want to do that.